# limes superior: equivalent condition

Tags: asymptotics, limsup-and-liminf

I was wondering if the following statement is true, and if my proof works. I also wonder if the statement is true if I allow $a=\pm\infty$?

*Statement*:
Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Then $$a=\limsup_{r\to\infty}f(r)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \forall\varepsilon>0: a-\varepsilon\stackrel{n}{<}f(r)\stackrel{as}{<}a+\varepsilon$$
(where $\stackrel{n}{<}$ means that the inequality holds for a sequence $(r_n)$ tending to infinity and $\stackrel{as}{<}$ means that the inequality holds asymptotically, i.e. for all $r>r_0$).

*Proof*:
''$\Rightarrow$'' Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then there exists $R_0$ such that for $R\geq R_0$:
$$
0\leq\sup_{r\geq R}f(r)-a\leq\varepsilon/2
$$
implying $f(r)\stackrel{as}{<}a+\varepsilon$.

Assume (for contradiction) that there does not exist a sequence $(r_n)$ tending to infinity and satisfying $a-\varepsilon<f(r_n)$ for all $n$. Then there must exist $R_0$ such that $a-\varepsilon\geq f(r)$ for al $r\geq R_0$. But then
$$
a-\varepsilon\geq\sup_{r\geq R_0}f(r)\geq\limsup_{r\to\infty}f(r)=a.
$$
A contradiction.

''$\Leftarrow$'' Since for all $\varepsilon>0$, $f(r)\stackrel{as}{<}a+\varepsilon$, we have that
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0\:\exists R_{\varepsilon}:\quad a+\varepsilon\geq\sup_{r\geq R_\varepsilon}f(r)\geq\limsup_{r\to\infty}f(r),
$$
proving that $a\geq\limsup_{r\to\infty}f(r)$.

Since for all $\varepsilon>0$, $a-\varepsilon\stackrel{n}{<}f(r)$, we have that $$
\forall\varepsilon>0\:\forall R\in\mathbb{R}\:\exists r>R:\quad a-\varepsilon<f(r).
$$
Hence
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0\:\forall R\in\mathbb{R}:\quad a-\varepsilon<\sup_{r\geq R}f(r),
$$
which implies
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0:\quad a-\varepsilon\leq\limsup_{r\to\infty}f(r),
$$
proving that $a\leq\limsup_{r\to\infty}f(r)$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. The extensions of the characterization you suggest to $a=\pm\infty$ are $$\limsup_{r\to\infty}f(r)=+\infty\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \forall x: f(r)\stackrel{n}{>}x$$ and $$\limsup_{r\to\infty}f(r)=-\infty\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \forall x: f(r)\stackrel{as}{<}x$$